# Lambda Throttles event, how to read the metric correctly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When running Lambda in high concurrency, I know it will raise the error ConcurrentInvocationLimitExceeded, my account has a soft limit of 10 concurrency, but when I write a script to test lambda load, I invoke my function 20 times, which is double the soft limit, and I hope that the Throttles metric should be 10, but when I opened it up, this gave me 26, which made me confused.

[image]

Also, the Total Concurrent Executions table doesn't reach 10 as my soft limit.
[image]

My first thought was that Lambda was retrying to run these throttles, but there are no retries in the Cloudwatch log.

For the Lambda function, I left it at the default setting and modified the code to sleep for 2 seconds before return the client (the lambda timeout is 3 seconds), and I checked the logs that confirmed the function had completed successfully.

My test script in JS:

```
const { LambdaClient, InvokeCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-lambda"); // CommonJS import
const client = new LambdaClient();

const ITER = 20;

const exec = async() => {
    const input = {
        FunctionName: "throttling-test",
    };
    const command = new InvokeCommand(input);

    const tasks = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < ITER; i++) {
        tasks.push(client.send(command));
    }

    const response = await Promise.all(tasks);
}

exec()
```

My question is: why do my throttles count up to 26 or more instead of 10?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without detailed logs (from both the client and lambda) it will be hard to say for sure but its likely that following is happening:

The local lambda client created in the test script has a builtin [retry behavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/feature-retry-behavior.html) in *addition* to lambda retry behavior.  Setting the max attempts your client uses to `1` might be useful along with setting logging to debug.

[The Lambda Operator Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/throttling.html) has a dedicated page with a *little* more info on this topic that you may find helpful, but I think the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/on-demand-scaling.html is one of the better resources to help build a 'mental model' on what is happening